# How to build frequency matrix in R?

Tags: r, frequency, crosstab

Suppose that the existing data frame named as `A` contains the following data:

```
Time    Var
T1      loc1
T1      loc2
T1      loc3
T2      loc2
T2      loc2
T2      loc3
T3      loc1
T3      loc3
T3      loc3
```

I want the output frequency matrix in R in the following format

```
      loc1    loc2    loc3
T1     1       1       1
T2     0       2       1
T3     1       0       2
```

I tried using `apply()`, `table()` but could not understand how to use them to get my required output. 
Can somebody suggest me some functions in R which I can use to get the required output?

Comment: Simply `table(A)`

Comment: Which is equivalent to doing: `table(A$Time, A$Var)`

Comment: Or equivalently: `with(A, table(Time, Var))`

Answer (score 3):

You could go for `xtabs` in base R

```
xtabs(~Time+Var, A)

#    Var
#Time loc1 loc2 loc3
#  T1    1    1    1
#  T2    0    2    1
#  T3    1    0    2
```

---

OR `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(A, Time~Var)
```

Comment: dcast is giving the required output. Thanks.